# How can I get the value from a control using the name of the control source?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to write some code to audit changes made via a form. I have a function that works to do this:

```vb
Function WriteChanges()

Dim f As Form
Dim c As Control
Dim user As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim MySet As ADODB.Recordset
Dim tbld As TableDef
Dim recsource As String

Set f = Screen.ActiveForm
Set db = CurrentDb
Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set MySet = New ADODB.Recordset
recsource = f.RecordSource
Set tbld = db.TableDefs(recsource)

pri_key = fFindPrimaryKeyFields(tbld)
Debug.Print "pri_key: "; pri_key
user = Environ("username")


MySet.Open "Audit", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

For Each c In f.Controls
    Select Case c.ControlType
        Case acTextBox, acComboBox, acListBox, acOptionGroup
            If c.Value <> c.OldValue Then
                With MySet
                    .AddNew
                        ![EditDate] = Now
                        ![user] = user
                        ![SourceTable] = f.RecordSource
                        ![SourceField] = c.ControlSource
                        ![BeforeValue] = c.OldValue
                        ![AfterValue] = c.Value
                    .update
                End With
            End If
    End Select
Next c

MySet.Close
Set MySet = Nothing
Set f = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

I use this function on the before update property of various forms and it populates the Audit table with the details of the changes to values in each of the controls. I need to also get the value from the primary key field to add to the Audit table. I can use the following code to identify the name of the primary key within the form's record source:

```vb
Function fFindPrimaryKeyFields(tdf As TableDef) As String

Dim idx As Index

On Error GoTo HandleIt

For Each idx In tdf.Indexes
    If idx.Primary Then
        fFindPrimaryKeyFields = Replace(idx.Fields, "+", "")
        GoTo OutHere
    End If
Next idx

OutHere:
Set idx = Nothing
Exit Function

HandleIt:
Select Case Err
    Case 0
    Resume Next
    Case Else
    Beep
    MsgBox Err & " " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    fFindPrimaryKeyFields = vbNullString
    Resume OutHere
End Select

End Function
```

How can I use this to get the value from the control (text box) that has the identified primary key as its control source.

Please forgive any silly errors in my code as I'm a relative novice. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want exactly, but if you have the name of the field, you can use the following:

```vb
Dim primaryKeyValue As Variant
Dim primaryKeyColumnName As String
primaryKeyColumnName = fFindPrimaryKeyFields(TableDefs!MyTable)
Dim f as Form
'Get the form somehow

Dim c As Control
On Error GoTo NextC 'Escape errors because lots of controls don't have a control source
For Each c In f.Controls
    If c.ControlSource = primaryKeyColumnName Then
        primaryKeyValue = c.Value
    End If
NextC:
Next c
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I'm getting the contents from all three text boxes on the form. These are the only three controls (ID, Name1 and Name2) on the form with control sources (ID, Name1, Name2). The first bit of the code correctly identifies the primary key field as ID however when I use debug.print primaryKeyValue within the for next loop I get the values of each control twice along with two blank values. I can't understand why I get this as only one controlsource should be equal to the primarykeycolumnname string

Comment: Apologies I see you edited your answer that now gives me the correct value. For some reason multiple times when I add debug.print primaryKeyValue but I don't think that will be a problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One debug.print can only return one value. If it's returning it multiple times, that's because you're running this piece of code multiple times.

Comment: The debug.print primaryKeyValue  is within the for each c in f.controls loop.

Comment: Well, if it isn't between the `If` and the `End If`, that should indeed run loads of times,

Comment: It is between the If and the End If but I get the following results: Auto_Logo0
pri_keyvalue: 
Auto_Header0
pri_keyvalue: 
txtID
pri_keyvalue:  1 
lblID
pri_keyvalue:  1 
lblName1
pri_keyvalue:  1 
lblName2
pri_keyvalue:  1  I'm confused

Comment: Still produces the same results??

Comment: Well, it's not really a problem, is it? I guess the error trapping doesn't work as expected, probably because you don't have `Option Explicit` at the top. But the value returned is always valid, isn't it?

Comment: No its not really a problem. Probably something daft that I'm doing. Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

If the primary key column is part of the form record source, you can simply read it by:

```
Debug.Print "PK value: " & f(pri_key)
```

Every column of the record source is a form property at runtime, independent of whether there is a control with the same name.

Note: your whole construct will stop working if you have a form that is based on a query that joins multiple tables.